# Logic of forward or backward difference coding

Tags: categorical-encoding, contrasts

Two systems of [contrast coding](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/) for ordinal data are *forward difference coding* and *backward difference coding*. I will focus on the latter system here because it seems to be more commonly used, but my confusion applies to both. Backward difference coding is defined as follows ([source](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables/#backward)),

> [...] The mean of the dependent variable for one level of the categorical variable is compared to the mean of the dependent variable for the prior adjacent level.  [...] The first comparison compares the mean [...] for level 2 with the mean [...] for level 1 [...].  The second comparison compares the mean [...] for level 3 minus level 2, and the third comparison compares the mean [...] for level 4 minus level 3.

To the best of my understanding, logically this should be coded as follows. Columns are comparisons and rows are levels.

```
      [,1] [,2]  [,3] 
[1,]    -1    0     0
[2,]     1   -1     0
[3,]     0    1    -1
[4,]     0    0     1
```

In the first comparison, the first row, representing data belonging to the first level, is contrasted against the second row, representing a data point belonging to second level. The third and fourth levels have no influence. In the second comparison, the second and third levels are contrasted; the first and fourth levels do not influence the contrast. In the third comparison, the contrast is between the third and fourth levels.

However, this is not how backward difference coding actually works. Here is the true coding,

```
      [,1] [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] -0.75 -0.5 -0.25
[2,]  0.25 -0.5 -0.25
[3,]  0.25  0.5 -0.25
[4,]  0.25  0.5  0.75
```

I don't understand how this conforms to the definition of backward difference masking. In the first comparison, the first level is contrasted with *the mean of all the other levels*. In the second comparison, the mean of the first two levels is contrasted with the mean of the second two levels. In the third comparison, the contrast is between the mean of all levels except the fourth and the fourth level.

So under backward difference coding, all levels influence all comparisons, even though according to its definition, this is not supposed to happen. How does this coding system conform to its definition?

Comment: I think section 10.8 here explains the difference between the "coding" matrix and the actual contrasts (which include the contribution of the intercepts): https://bookdown.org/pingapang9/linear_models_bookdown/contrasts.html